# How to fix my naming of a new column based on another column in my data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

My code seems to work fine, but I am having issues further down my analysis because there are some hidden factors in my code. I have added columns Microbe and have no issues there. But I think my Microbe.PR column may be the first part of my problem.

I have data from a test that requires adding a dilution column based on the values in the "conc.dil" column, and adding a killing column based on the BKA column. this is all based on the Microbe.PR column as well.

My data look likes this:

```
    SampleID        Date Conc.Dil          BKA Microbe Microbe.PR Dilution Killing
1577   102364  08.12.2018 0.003906 3.175029e+00      EC       ECSK      D12     K12
1578   102364  08.12.2018 0.005859 8.943744e-03      EC       ECSK      D11     K11
1579   102364  08.12.2018 0.007813 6.573652e+00      EC       ECSK      D10     K10
1580   102364  08.12.2018 0.011719 1.833467e+00      EC       ECSK       D9      K9
1581   102364  08.12.2018 0.015625 6.707808e-01      EC       ECSK       D8      K8
1582   102364  08.12.2018 0.023438 1.007692e+02      EC       ECSK       D7      K7
```

My Microbe.PR code looks like this:

```
EC$Microbe.PR <- 
  ifelse (EC$Protocol.File.Name == "KILLER E COLI protocolHC","ECSK",
          ifelse(EC$Protocol.File.Name == "KILLER E COLI protocolUSF", "ECSK",
                 ifelse(EC$Protocol.File.Name == "KILLER E COLI protocol", "ECSK",
                        ifelse(EC$Protocol.File.Name == "E COLI protocol", "EC", 
                               ifelse(EC$Protocol.File.Name == "E COLI protocolUSF", "EC", "EC")))))
```

When I run this code these are my results:

```
EC$Microbe.PR <- as.factor(EC$Microbe.PR)
> levels(EC$Microbe.PR)
[1] "EC"   "ECSK"

> EC_SK <- subset(EC, EC$Microbe.PR %in% c("ECSK"))
> levels(EC_SK$Microbe.PR)
[1] "EC"   "ECSK"
```

When I do the levels with EC_SK there should be no "EC" values in Microbe.PR. When I do a summary on this it says there are 0 values for "EC" and 1120 values for ECSK which is correct.

Comment: Factor levels will stay the same as when the factor was created, even if not present in the current iteration of your data, until you drop them explicitly. You can use `droplevels` on either a single vector or an entire data frame, or subset of columns in a data frame

Comment: Instead of the heavily-nested `ifelse` statements, you might consider `match` or `dplyr::case_when`: much more readable/maintainable.

Comment: or a left join with a lookup table, so all the input is structured

Comment: I got the case_when function to work, but am having trouble with the droplevels. Is this the only way to get the droplevels to work
`summary(EC_SK$Microbe.PR1)
  EC ECSK 
   0 1120 
> summary(droplevels(EC_SK)$Microbe.PR1)
ECSK 
1120 ` I would like the first line of code to work after doing the droplevels, so I only have to do it once.

Comment: Do you need the factors to be factors?  Maybe you could add a `mutate_if(is.factor, ~{as.character(.x)})`